# Exception after rotation in Android 10 when using ACTION_SEND intent

Tags: android

I'm getting an Exception after rotation in Android 10 when using **ACTION_SEND** intent.
Earlier Android versions are OK (no exception).

I've created a bare-bones Android app that shows the problem.
It is a single activity with a button.
Pressing the button displays the Share dialog.
Rotate the screen.
App goes away (on Android 10).

```
package com.example.test1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  
    Button btnTest;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        
        btnTest = findViewById( R.id.btnTest );
        btnTest.setOnClickListener( v -> this.DoTest1()  );
    }
    
   
    void DoTest1()
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction( Intent.ACTION_SEND );
        sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject" );
        sendIntent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text" );
        sendIntent.setType( "text/plain" );
        this.startActivity( sendIntent );
    }
}
```

---

Exception occurs here:

[C:\Android\Sdk\sources\android-29\android\contentContextWrapper.java]

```
@Override
public ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfo() 
{
    return mBase.getApplicationInfo(); // <-- mBase is null !
}
```

Anyone else seeing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `Intent.createChooser.`

> Builds a new ACTION_CHOOSER Intent that wraps the given target intent,
> also optionally supplying a title. If the target intent has specified
> FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION,
> then these flags will also be set in the returned chooser intent, with
> its ClipData set appropriately: either a direct reflection of
> getClipData() if that is non-null, or a new ClipData built from
> getData().

```
  Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
  startActivity(shareIntent);
```